# Duplicate project reference entries in a .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, csproj

I was recently checking in a change to a c# project and during the checkin, I had to do a manual merge on the .csproj file.  While doing the merge, I noticed that there were duplicate entries for all the project references in the project.

Specifically, the ProjectReference tag was duplicated for each other project referenced in the project being merged.  Like so:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\DataSourceInterfaces\DataSourceInterfaces.csproj">
  <Project>{335ED423-8DC5-4D56-86D6-9A1B0F7DB0B9}</Project>
  <Name>DataSourceInterfaces</Name>
</ProjectReference>
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\DataSourceInterfaces\DataSourceInterfaces.csproj">
  <Project>{335ED423-8DC5-4D56-86D6-9A1B0F7DB0B9}</Project>
  <Name>DataSourceInterfaces</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

If I go into the Visual Studio UI and delete the reference to the DataSourceInterfaces project, only one of the tags is removed, and the next time I load the project, the reference shows up in the reference list as if it hadn't been removed.

This is easily fixable by manually removing the duplicate entries and doesn't seem to cause any problems, but I'm wondering what could have caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: The exact same problem is happening with me, but not only duplicates: I find 10x ou 20x repetitions of the same references! My csproj is currently with more than 11k lines and I guess the majority of them are duplicates. I'm using VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering what could have caused the problem in the first place.

It sounds like your merge tool failed during the manual merge, and added duplicate project references.  When you merge manually, you need to take care that this type of thing doesn't happen - all it takes is a slight difference in things like indentation or whitespace changes to occasionally mess up some merging tools (this depends a lot on the tool in question, though).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Reed.  The problem is the duplicate entries existed prior to the merge operation.  I found by accident, during the merge, but they weren't part of the conflict I had to resolve.  We use Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010 for our tools.  I suppose it could have happened during a previous merge someone else did, true, so it could still be the result of a badly executed manual merge.